# perl libSqliteIcu.so collate icu

Tags: perl, sqlite, icu, collate

The **libSqliteIcu** works fine in **sqlite3 terminal** with:

```
sqlite3
...
.load './libSqliteIcu.so'
SELECT icu_load_collation('pl_PL', 'POLISH');
SELECT DISTINCT miasto FROM tab ORDER BY miasto COLLATE POLISH;
```

How to code the sequence above into **perl**?

Answer (score 1):

Untested:

```
use DBI qw();
my $dbh = DBI->connect('DBI:SQLite:thedatabase.sqlite');
$dbh->sqlite_enable_load_extension(1);
$dbh->do(q{SELECT load_extension('./libSqliteIcu.so')});
$dbh->do(q{SELECT icu_load_collation('pl_PL', 'POLISH')};
my $miasto = $dbh->selectall_arrayref(q{SELECT DISTINCT miasto FROM tab ORDER BY miasto COLLATE POLISH});
```

---

---

Alternatively, sort in Perl:

```
use utf8;
my @tongue_twister = qw(Król Karol kupił królowej Karolinie korale koloru koralowego);
```

---

```
use Unicode::ICU::Collator qw();    # ICU C library, fast
my $c = Unicode::ICU::Collator->new('pl_PL');
```

---

```
use Unicode::Collate qw();          # pure-perl, slow
my $c = Unicode::Collate->new(locale => 'pl_PL');
```

---

```
my @sorted = $c->sort(@tongue_twister);
# (
#     'Karol',
#     'Karolinie',
#     'koloru',
#     'korale',
#     'koralowego',
#     'Król',
#     'królowej',
#     'kupił'
# )
```

Comment: **DBD::SQLite::db do failed: unable to delete/modify user-function due to active statements error during initialization:  at** [and the code line is:] **$dbh->do(q{SELECT load_extension('./libSqliteIcu.so')});**

Comment: `$dbh->do(q{SELECT load_extension ...` did not work for me. I got "error during initialization". But this worked: `$dbh->sqlite_load_extension('libicu');` (Also, while compiling the sqlite3 shared library, I had to use `libicu.so` instead of `libSqliteIcu.so`).

Answer (score 0):

One simple, *but not perfect*, solution is to use `pl_PL.UTF8` locale.

In **sqlite3** we prepare:

```
create table A(idA);
...
insert into A values('ź');
insert into A values('Ż');
insert into A values('ź');
insert into A values('Š');
...
insert into A values('ś');
...
```

and now:

```
select * from A;
```

gives: **Z ź Ż ź z ś ż S Š z**.

So we load:

```
.load './libSqliteIcu.so'
SELECT icu_load_collation('pl_PL', 'POLISH');
select idA from A order by idA collate POLISH;
```

and we have: **S Š ś z z Z ź ź ż Ż**.

So now in **perl** we can put:

```
SELECT idA FROM A ORDER BY idA
```

and get *not correct* order: **S Z z z ś Š ź ź Ż ż**

Now, with **perllocale** we put in **perl**:

```
SELECT idA FROM A ORDER BY idA COLLATE perllocale
```

and get *the order*: **S Š ś z z Z ź ź ż Ż**.

The `$dbh->do(q{SELECT load_extension('./libSqliteIcu.so')});` does not work in my case; it makes an error:

> DBD::SQLite::db do failed: unable to delete/modify user-function due to active statements error during initialization

Comment: POSIX locales are obviated by the advent of Unicode. Perl has exquisite Unicode support.